# Unknown column '' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql

My query is throwing up this error. Can anyone see why?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Units WHERE ID = `$uniqueUnits[a]`";
```

> Unknown column '' in 'where clause'

Comment: What is in `$uniqueUnits[a]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems.

- You're using backticks to delimit a string. Backticks delimit *fields*, so MySQL thinks you're trying to give it a column name.
- The error message indicates that, in fact, this value that it thinks is a column name, is empty. So your value `$uniqueUnits[a]` is probably broken, or not being interpolated correctly.

---

You should do the following:

- [Interpolate your variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) explictly with the "complex syntax" to be sure that the string forms properly;
- *Check* the value of `$query` so that you can see what's going on:

  ```
  print $query;
  ```
- Use actual quotation marks to delimit strings:

  ```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM Units WHERE ID = '{$uniqueUnits[a]}'";
  //                                       ^ quote
  //                                        ^ PHP variable interpolation
  ```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Units WHERE ID = '$uniqueUnits[a]'";
                                         ^---            ^---
```

Backticks are for escaping reserved words, so mysql is translating your variable's contents into a field name.

Answer (score 0):

Because apparently $uniqueUnits[a] resolves to the empty string. And there is no column like this in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding your array with `{}`, like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Units WHERE ID = `{$uniqueUnits[a]}`";
```

Also, is column `ID` actually in your table?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php Search for "The following is okay, as it's inside a string"

Comment: My apologies. Thanks Tomalak. If I don't get any more activity on this answer, I'll delete it.

Comment: Everything aside from the final two sentences is perfectly correct, so you could just edit it!